# Do generating sets of ideals increase if ideals increase?

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

Suppose I have a ring $R$ (let's say an integral domain), and two finitely generated ideals $I\subseteq J$. Is it true that the minimum size of a generating set of $I$ can't be larger than the minimum size of a generating set of $J$?

I can't prove it but I also can't think of a counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $J = R$ and let $I \subsetneq R$ be a finitely-generated non-principal ideal.
Then $J = (1)$ but $(x) \subsetneq I$ for every $x \in I$.
Take for example $R = \mathbb{Q}[X,Y]$ and $I = (X,Y)$.

Comment: While it answers the question as stated, I feel the correct response to this answer is to restrict the question to proper ideals

Answer (score 1):

I intended for $J\neq R$ but the principle of Jendrik's answer extends: Let $J=(a)$ be some principal ideal and $I_0$ be a non-principal ideal (say, $I_0=(x,y)$). Then define $I:=I_0J=(ax,ay)\subseteq J$.

If $I$ is not principal, that disproves the claim. If $I$ is principal, let's say $I=(z)$, then $ax=bz$ and $ay=cz$ for some $b,c\in R$. But also, $(z)=I\subseteq J=(a)$, so $z\in (a)$ and hence $z=da$ for some $d$. Thus $ax=bda$ and $ay=cda$, and thus $x=bd$ and $y=cd$. But this means $I_0=(x,y)\subseteq (d)$, which also disproves the claim.

Comment: **1)** I think you need to add that $I \subsetneq J = (a)$ so that $d$ is not a unit, thus $(d) \neq R$ and therefore $(x,y) = (d)$, giving the contradiction.

**2)** I think you can shorten the argument a bit: Taking $J = (x)$ we have $I = (x^2, xy)$.
For $z \in R$ we then have $I = (z)$ iff $z$ is a gcd of $x^2, xy$, i.e. if $I = (\operatorname{gcd}(x^2,xy)) = (x)$.
(This is not the case because $I \subseteq (x^2, xy, y^2) \subsetneq (x)$, where the strict inequality follows from the fact that $(x^2, xy, y^2)$ has a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis given by all $x^n y^m$ with $n+m \geq 2$.)